# Using malloc( ) and free( ) in a C program without getting (lldb)

Tags: c, malloc

This is the first program I've written using `malloc()` and `free()`. It looks correct to me, and when I reference my book, it looks very similar to examples in the book. However, when I run the program I get an `(lldb)` prompt.

I enter, say, 8 for the number of elements and 2 for the initialization value. My xcode compiler says back "(lldb)".

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int * make_array(int elem, int val);
void show_array(const int ar[], int n);
int main(void)
{
int *pa;
int size;
int value;

printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
while (size > 0) {
    printf("Enter the initialization value: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    pa = make_array(size, value);
    if (pa)
    {
        show_array(pa, size);
        free (pa);
    }
    printf("Enter the number of elements (<1 to quit): ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
}
printf("Done.\n");
return 0;
}

int * make_array(int elem, int val)
{
int index;
int * ptd;

ptd = (int *) malloc(elem * sizeof (int));

for (index = 0; index < elem; index++)
    ptd[index] = val;

return ptd;
}

void show_array(const int ar[], int size)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d",ar[i]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I get (lldb) as the result."*?

Comment: What is "lldb" in this context?

Comment: Hi, I just updated above. I enter 8 and 2. The compiler says back "(lldb)". How do I get it to read me back the numbers like I programmed it to?

Comment: Seeing `(lldb) ` indicates that your program has crashed, and the crash has been caught by the LLDB debugger.

Comment: thanks, @duskwuff. Any idea how I can get around it crashing? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try typing `run` in the `(lldb)` prompt? Otherwise, you can try `where` or `backtrace`.

Comment: see my answer below. the program compiles and runs.

Comment: @user315052 OK, i tried that and it identified a "breakpoint" where free() was called. I simply unchecked the breakpoint botton at the top of the screen, ran it again, and now it works.

Comment: I've corrected the capitalization in your title. `Malloc()` and `malloc()` are two distinct identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program compiles and runs (probably as you expected). Here is example output:

```
Enter the number of elements: 5
Enter the initialization value: 12
1212121212
Enter the number of elements (<1 to quit): 8
Enter the initialization value: 2
22222222
Enter the number of elements (<1 to quit): 100
Enter the initialization value: 34
34343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343434
Enter the number of elements (<1 to quit): -1
Done.
```

Comment: did you have to change anything to get it to run? when i press run i just get "(lldb)"

Comment: nope. I compiled it on a 64-bit linux machine with clang default flags.

Comment: I just compiled with xcode as well (which uses apples clang as compiler). it runs.

Comment: thanks, i got it now. for some reason it wasn't working because it identified the free() function call as a breakpoint. i simply unchecked it

Comment: That would mean you set that line as a breakpoint, and your application dropped into the debugger when it hit that line. There was nothing wrong at all.